# Can't set system properties using node.js sdk

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk, iot, azure-iot-edge

I need to set system properties on a module written using the node.js SDK, otherwise the message body is sent forward base64 encoded. I can't find anything on the sdk. I can set application propertes, but that  doesn't help;

```
  outputMsg.properties.add('Content-Encoding', 'utf-8');  
  outputMsg.properties.add('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

This how the event looks like in event grid:

```
{ 
  "id": "d72588fa-0141-d3e3-50ca-5fa8dc14b452",  
  "topic": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/55AE1D7B-63B3-4993-811D-6FDD3B176255/RESOURCEGROUPS/SJ-POC-RG/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DEVICES/IOTHUBS/SJPOC",  
  "subject": "devices/sjedge/nomadClient",  
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Devices.DeviceTelemetry",  
  "data": {. 
    "properties": {. 
      "Content-Encoding": "utf-8",  
      "Content-Type": "application/json". 
    },  
    "systemProperties": {. 
      "iothub-connection-device-id": "sjedge",  
      "iothub-connection-module-id": "some-client",   
      "iothub-connection-auth-method": "{\"scope\":\"module\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}",  
      "iothub-connection-auth-generation-id": "637667822113671571",  
      "iothub-enqueuedtime": "2021-09-20T10:25:02.425Z",  
      "iothub-message-source": "Telemetry". 
    },  
    "body":  "eyJjdCI6MTYzMDQxNjE3MCwidmUiOjEsImVycm9yIjoibm9uZSIsImxhdCI6MC4wMTA0ODkyNDcyOTY4ODUxNjIsImxvbmciOjAuNDM2MTM0MzMxMjQ3NTY1Miwic3BlZWQiOjgwLjIyNzM3MDMwMDg1OTA4LCJzYXRzIjo4LCJncHNTYXRzIjoxMiwiYmVhcmluZyI6MTMxLjU3OTQ3NzUxNDMwMzE0LCJzb3VyY2UiOiI5Mi0wMSIsImFsdCI6MzYuOTE2ODAwOTIxODIzMzV9"
  },  
  "dataVersion": "",  
  "metadataVersion": "1",  
  "eventTime": "2021-09-20T10:25:02.425Z".   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how one does it:

outputMsg.contentEncoding = 'utf-8';
outputMsg.contentType = 'application/json';